# MVC project redirect to ?ReturnUrl=%2f

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I have a .net 4.5 mvc project with forms autentication, the project redirects me to `?Http://myserver/login?ReturnUrl=%2f` when i try to in home web page. why happend this thing or how is happend. In my web.config i have the following code:

`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="100" path="/" defaultUrl="/home/index" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>`

how can i do for redirect to home/index without redirect to login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AllowAnonymous vs OverrideAuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043934/allowanonymous-vs-overrideauthorizeattribute)

Answer (score 0):

```
loginUrl="~/login"
```

this is what taking you to login page everytime so changing this url to the url of your home or index page might help or just removing this might also work